# Problema de conexión PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy realizando una clase que contiene una serie de métodos que hacen consultas a una base de datos. Esta clase no tiene una funcionalidad visible, es decir, que no tengo salida por pantalla para ver los resultados que produce. Simplemente es una clase que va a pasar por un código test con PHPUnit para probar su funcionalidad. La cuestión es que tras pasar el test, tanto por terminal como por la extensión de Visual Studio, me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error : Call to a member function query() on null. No sé exactamente a lo que hace referencia ni sé cómo solucionarlo, de ahí que solicite ayuda.

A continuación, dejo un fragmento de código (porque es muy largo) para que veáis lo que hace.

Respecto a la conexión con la base de datos, a mi entender se produce, ya que una de las cosas que tengo que hacer (no con la clase, sino en otro archivo) es crear un par de tablas con HTML con el contenido de las tablas de la base de datos y estas se crean sin problemas.

En fin, espero que podáis ayudarme. Gracias por adelantado.

```
<?php

class gestionLibros {

    function conexion($host, $user, $pass, $bd){
     try{
        $conexion = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $bd);
        return $conexion;
     }catch (Exception $e){
         null;
     }
    }

    function consultarAutores($conexion, $autor = null){
        if ($autor == null) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM autor"; 
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM autor WHERE id='$autor'";
        }

        $queryResult = $conexion->query($sql);

        if ($queryResult->num_rows > 0 && !$conexion->error) {
            $resultado = $queryResult->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return $resultado;
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    function consultarLibros($conexion, $autor = null) {
        if ($autor == null) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM libro"; 
        }else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM libro WHERE id_autor='$autor'";
        }

        $queryResult = $conexion->query($sql);

        if ($queryResult->num_rows > 0 && !$conexion->error) {
            $resultado = $queryResult->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return $resultado;
        }else{
            return null;
        }   
    }

    function consultarDatosLibro($conexion, $libro) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM libro WHERE id='$libro'";
        $queryResult = $conexion->query($sql);

        if ($queryResult->num_rows > 0 && !$conexion->error) {
            $resultado = $queryResult->fetch_assoc();
            return $resultado;
        }else{
            return null;
        }   
    }

    function borrarLibro($conexion, $libro) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM libro WHERE id='$libro'";

        $queryResult = $conexion->query($sql);

        if ($queryResult && !$conexion->error) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function borrarAutor($conexion, $autor) {
        $conexion->autocommit(FALSE);
        $conexion->begin_transaction();
        $conexion->query("SET foreign_key_checks = 0");
        $all_query_ok= true;

        $sql = "DELETE FROM autor WHERE id=$autor";
        $conexion->query($sql) ? NULL : $all_query_ok = false;

        $sql = "DELETE FROM libro WHERE id_autor=$autor";
        $conexion->query($sql) ? NULL : $all_query_ok = false;

        $conexion->autocommit(TRUE);
        $conexion->query("SET foreign_key_checks = 1");
        
        if ($all_query_ok) {
            $conexion->commit();
            return true;
        } else {
            $conexion->rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }
    
} 
?>
```

Añado: el método borrarAutor pretende borrar el autor y, mediante una transacción, borrar todos los libros asociados a él.

Añado también el fragmento que hace de llamada a la conexión

```
<?php

require_once 'gestionLibros.php';
    
$libros = new GestionLibros();

$conexion = $libros->conexion("localhost", "root", "", "libros");
$autores = $libros->consultarAutores($conexion);
$libros = $libros->consultarLibros($conexion);
?>
```

Nota: he añadido el código completo

Comment: Una cosita... no estás intentando conectar PHP con PHPMyadmin, estás intentando conectar PHP con (imagino) MySql. PHPMyadmin es un SGBD (Sistema gestor de bases de datos), no una base de datos como tal. Tu PHPMyadmin está conectándose también a tu MySql, por cierto.

Comment: @Benito-B me parece que ascendiste a PHPMyAdmin diciendo que es un SGBD. Según tengo entendido el SGBD sería MySQL, mientras que PHPMyAdmin no es otra cosa que un programa (cliente) para manejar MySQL.

Comment: Toda la razón, @A.Cedano. Me refería a que PHPMyAdmin es el "cliente", y con las prisas le llamé de manera equivocada. El SGBD sería efectivamente MySql, mientras que el motor sería MariaDB o InnoDB (o el que corresponda, vaya), si no me equivoco ahora :)

Comment: Lo que dices de [los motores (engine)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engines.html) es totalmente correcto @Benito-B. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El error:

> `Call to a member function query() on null`

Significa que el objeto que estás usando para invocar a `query` es nulo.

Supongamos que el problema ocurre aquí:

```
    $queryResult = $conexion->query($sql);
```

Pues significa que `$conexion` ahí es nulo.

Debes investigar entonces por qué `$conexion` es nulo.

Intentaré mejorar tu código, aunque (creo que te lo comenté en otra pregunta), lo que tú necesitas realmente es una clase envoltorio (wrapper) para manejar la conexión. Como estás programando actualmente, si tú vas a usar la conexión desde 1 millón de contextos, tendrás que pasar las credenciales de conexión desde ese millón de contextos, y datos sensibles como esos estarán rodando por toda la aplicación.

Implementando una clase envoltorio, las credenciales estarían en esa sola clase, aumentando la seguridad. Otra ventaja es que si por ejemplo la contraseña cambia, o el nombre de la base de datos, no tendrías que ir al millón de contextos a cambiarlas, sino que las cambiarías solamente en tu clase envoltorio.

Otra cosa que conviene aclarar es que, a diferencia de PDO, `mysqli` no levanta una `Exception` si hay errores de conexión. Lo digo porque no puedes envolver el constructor de la clase dentro de un bloque `try ... catch` sin más. Hay formas de hacerlo, pero no creo que valga la pena. Los errores de conexión son delicados (pueden revelar las credenciales de conexión por ejemplo) y creo que con verificar si la conexión es `null`  o no, bastaría.

La clase envoltorio podría quedar así:

```
<?php
class DbMySqli extends mysqli{
    private $host="localhost";
    private $user="root";
    private $pass="";
    private $bd="libros";
    private static $mMysqli;
    
    // Constructor
    public function __construct() {     
        parent::__construct($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->bd);
        
        /* 
            Manejo de errores ...
            Si no quieres escribir errores en el log
            Puedes omitir esto y debes tratarlo con cuidado
            en algunos casos, las credenciales podrían escribirse en el log
            y usuarios mal intencionados podrían obtener
            esa información para perpetrar ataques
        */
        if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
            trigger_error("Error de conexión MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(),
            E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    /*
        Dejamos el método mágico clone vacío
        para prevenir duplicados de la conexión
    */
    private function __clone() { }

    
    /*
       Obtener la instancia de la conexión
    */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$_instance) { 
        /*
            Si no hay instancia, crea una
        */
            self::$mMysqli = new self();
        }
        self::$mMysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        return self::$mMysqli;
    }

    /*
       El método fetch_all sólo está disponible
       si PHP tiene instalado el controlado mysqlnd
       Verificamos eso, para si no, crear dicho método...
       Como esto, tú puedes definir otros métodos utilitarios,
       por ejemplo, aquellos que faciliten el manejo de 
       la obtención de resultados de consultas preparadas
       ver enlace al final
     */
    
    public function fetch_all($resulttype = MYSQLI_NUM)
    {
        if (method_exists('mysqli_result', 'fetch_all')) # Compatibilidad con PHP < 5.3
        $res = parent::fetch_all($resulttype);
        else
        for ($res = array(); $tmp = $this->fetch_array($resulttype);) $res[] = $tmp;        
        return $res;
    }
    
}
?>
```

Veamos ahora uno de tus métodos en lo que sería el archivo `GestionLibros.php`. De entrada, el método `conexion()` desaparecería de ese archivo. Tú vas a conectar desde fuera, allí donde necesites consultar libros... Otra gran ventaja de esto es que, puedes reutilizar la conexión para interactuar con otros archivos, imagina que además de gestionar libros, necesitas gestionar préstamos de libros, si tuvieras un archivo `GestionPrestamos.php` y conectas también desde él, vas a tener en ese contexto dos conexiones sin necesidad.

Además, la lógica contextual del estado de la conexión, debes ponerla aquí. Imaginemos que estás en un contexto de API, donde el cliente, en caso de error, necesita una respuesta de error. Eso debes controlarlo en este contexto.

Veamos el método:

```
function consultarAutores($conexion, $autor = null){
    if ($conexion) {
        if ($autor == null) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM autor"; 
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM autor WHERE id='$autor'";
        }

        $rs = $conexion->query($sql);
        $mData=$rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if ($mData) {
            $mData['status']=true;
        
        } else {
            $mData=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'No hay datos');
        }
    } else {
        $mData=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'No hay conexion');
    }
}
```

Finalmente, código en cualquier contexto:

```
require_once 'gestionLibros.php';
#Este sería el archivo con la clase envoltorio
require_once 'DbMysqli.php';
    
$libros = new GestionLibros();
$db=new DbMySqli();
$mysqli=$db->getInstance();

$autores = $libros->consultarAutores($conexion);

if ($autores['status']) {
    #Hay datos, leerlos
    var_dump($autores);
} else {
    #Ocurrió un error, lanzar tu política de errores
    echo $autores['msg'];
}
```

Si este código te dice que no hay conexión, es evidente que debes verificar por qué motivo no está conectado: credenciales, nombre de la base de datos, estado de la base de datos, etc. Esto es algo propio de tu contexto y escapa a lo que podamos hacer desde PHP.

Comment: Buenas A. Cedano. Con toda probabilidad tu propuesta de solución sea correcta, pero no lo es para mí en este caso, ya que este tipo de construcciones aún no las he visto/aprendido, por lo que debo de "apañar" el código con los conocimientos de los que dispongo. Al margen, lo que se me solicita es que lo haga de esta manera, encerrando todo en una única clase. No pretendo que el código tenga más utilidad en un futuro, ya que lo que estoy haciendo es algo así como un ejercicio práctico para aprender a hacer conexiones con BBDD y trabajar con clases.

Comment: De nuevo, al margen de esto, llevas razón en que el problema está justamente en las líneas del tipo $queryResult = $conexion->query($sql); lo que no termino de entender es por qué es null, si la conexión ocurre, ya que como decía en el post, las tablas de la base de datos salen por pantallas es decir, si la conexión fuera null, las llamadas

$autores = $libros->consultarAutores($conexion);
$libros = $libros->consultarLibros($conexion);

no volcarían los datos de las tablas en el html

En cualquier caso, te doy las gracias por la ayuda, de verdad

Comment: Lo que pretendo decir es que, por ejemplo, el método consultarAutores me permite volcar los datos de autores en un html, por lo que la conexión se ha establecido. Sin embargo, vas a la línea de código y aparece ese error que indica que no se está produciendo.

Comment: @dancareli si dices que funciona en otra parte, es posible entonces que estés anulando o cancelando la conexión. Convendría que agregues todo el código que hay en el contexto para revisarlo, puedes hacerlo editando la pregunta. Cuando se trate de ejercicios, conviene decirlo, aunque, sin ánimo de criticar a nadie, yo no enseñaría nunca a programar aplicando malas prácticas. Si por ejemplo enseñas de ese modo pensando que el alumno luego aprenderá cosas más avanzadas y eso no ocurre, el alumno se quedará con un "aprendizaje" viciado.

Comment: Ya he incluido todo el código. Inicialmente no lo hice porque me salía un error a la hora de publicarlo, pero ahora me lo ha permitido.

Al margen, me han comentado por otro lado que el problema podría estar en una mala configuración/instalación de PHPUnit, pero no sé si ese podría ser el caso

Comment: @dancareli yo no veo que la conexión se anule en ninguna parte del código, si es un problema de PHPUnit lo ignoro, es una herramienta que no uso y que no conozco. Pero tu código es demasiado raro. Por ejemplo, si estás en el contexto de una clase, lo propio sería declarar una propiedad para la conexión, algo así: `private $conexion;` luego asignarla cuando conectas (o en el constructor de la clase), algo así: `$this->conexion=new mysqli (...);` y en los otros métodos usar también `$this->conexion` en vez de **pasarle la conexión desde fuera, a la misma clase que la crea** ...

Comment: ...  no sé si te indicaron de hacer eso así ni por qué, pero es una forma muy rara de programar, y que no tiene mucha lógica. Si esto te es permitido, prueba a hacerlo así. No veo más motivos por los que la conexión pueda ser nula. Otra cosa que te recomiendo es que revises los logs de error si sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Como te comentaba, el código funciona porque la base de datos vuelca los datos en la web, visualizándose por pantalla. Seguramente el problema sea de PHPUnit, así que voy a eliminar el post e intentaré instalar correctamente PHPUnit.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No puedo eliminar la pregunta, por lo que voy a indicar que al final el problema estaba en el código que debía de utilizar en el test de PHPUnit. Ese código tenía una errata en la conexión a la BD, de ahi que mi código funcionara pero al pasarlo por PHPUnit diera problemas de conexión

Comment: @dancareli como dije más arriba, no uso PHPUnit. Cuando tengas un problema con un código, debes poner **ese** código en la pregunta, no otro código, a no ser que PHPUnit lo genere en base al código que muestras o algo así ¿?